# What's the correct syntax of passing an IBAction from a UICollectionViewCell to its host UIViewController?

Tags: delegates, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, ibaction

**Scenario:** processing a button action originating from a UICollectionViewCell in its hosting UIViewController.

The Cell: 
[image]

Here's my code:

```
protocol CellProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}
...
class ItemCollectionCell:UICollectionViewCell {
    var delegate:CellProtocol?
    var itemData:ItemData?
    @IBOutlet weak var descLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func addToCartAction() {
        delegate?.doSomething()
        print("Add to Cart")
    }
}


class ShopViewController:UIViewController, CellProtocol {

    let kCellID = "ItemCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var featuredItemLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var featuredItemPriceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var featuredItemImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("Howdy Batman!")
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - Action Methods

    @IBAction func addToCartAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

This isn't working. 
I know it has something to do with delegation.

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath method have you set the delegate to SELF?

Comment: I've done that just after I submitted my question.  It works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I merely sent 'self' to my custom UICollectionViewCell class during the cell-loading phase.